# Question about derivative of complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

[image: 1]

Ok... so from the statement I understand that $f$ is defined as $f:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ and $u$ is defined as $u:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. Ok.. I understand to take real derivative of $u$... and it will be $\frac{du}{dr} = \frac{1}{2+|f(re^{i \theta}|^2} \cdot \frac{d}{dr} |f(re^{i \theta})|^2$. But when transform $|f(re^{i \theta})|^2 = f(re^{i \theta}) \overline{f(re^{i \theta})}$ it becomes real derivative of complex function. How to calculate this?

Comment: Take into account that the derivative of the conjugate function is the conjugate of the derivate itself. The result exposed in the proof is a direct consequence of using this fact by applying the derivative of the product first. You will finally need the chain rule to notice both factors $e^{i\theta}$, $e^{-i\theta}$ respectively.

Comment: @YausetCabrera I still don't understand :(. Why derivative of conjugate function is conjugate of derivative itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you write $f(z) = u(z) + i v(z)$ where $u$ and $v$ are both real-valued functions, then $f'(z) = u'(z) + i v'(z)$ because the derivative is a linear operator, but also since $\overline{f(z)} = u(z) - i v(z)$ then $\overline{f(z)}' = u'(z) - i v'(z) = \overline{f'(z)}$.

Comment: Ok. Now I understand this. But how I can take derivative in function of $r$ from a complex function

Comment: You apply the chain rule. If we have $z = re^{i\theta}$, then $\frac{df}{dr} = \frac{df}{dz} \frac{dz}{dr} = f'(z) e^{i \theta}$.